# Deploying grunt based app in CloudControl

Tags: node.js, deployment, gruntjs, cloudcontrol

I'm trying to deploy a grunt based app to CC. I would like to deploy the `dist` version of the app, which is generated with the `grunt build` task. Right now, what I've done is to move my grunt `devDependencies` to `dependencies` and use the NPM `postinstall` hook to run the grunt build task. This way once updated NPM dependencies CC runs the task.

But, I've two issues with this approach:

**1)** `compass` is not working

**2)** it just doesn't feel correct to move all my grunt dependencies to `dependencies`. The first issue I think that I could fix it using another SCSS grunt module.

Any other alternative approach? Preferably I don't want to save my `dist` builds in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain the situation a little bit more?

Normally I would follow the following steps

## Local

1. Do the npm install
2. Do the grunt build
3. push to the cloud

   ## Server
4. Set the environment as production(assuming that all your files check for the environment and load files accordingly)